# voice recognition in mono

Tags: c#, mono, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

Is there any way to add voice recognition feature to mono application. There are a System.Speech (in .net) and Microsoft.Speech (in MS Speech Platform) namespaces, but I can't find any in Mono. So how is it possible to add speech recognition functionality in Mono?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at this link: 
[Mono System.Speech](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Speech)

It seems as though System.Speech.Recognition is now supported.  Are you pulling a recent (3.0+) tarball and building your own Mono runtime?

Answer (score 6):

I can't see any native C# engines. There is a Java engine called [Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/) that you could probably either call directly or via [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/). Alternatively you could use a web service, I found [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/api). Also there could be something interesting re HTML5 and Chrome in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647406/speech-recognition-web-services). No personal experience in any of these I am afraid (except for IKVM.NET).

Answer (score 1):

There actually is one native C# speech recognition Engine and it's called **Syn.Speech**. To reference it in Visual Studio Project just Launch the *Package Manager Console* and type

```
PM> Install-Package Syn.Speech
```

I couldn't find any comprehensive tutorial on it but heres the [Wiki Link](http://wiki.syn.co.in/)

Moreover theres this [demo application](https://github.com/SynHub/Syn.Speech.Demo)